# How to read a binary files and print 3's on screen?

Tags: c++, binary

I want to read a binary file of integer type and print the occurrence of the number of 3's in the file.  I somehow wrote a program to open and read a binary file.

Here is the couple of problems I am facing:

1. If I try to print the file on my terminal, the execution continues
   forever and the loop never ends.
2. I have no idea of how to filter out 3's from it.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
streampos size;
char * memblock;

ifstream file ("threesData.bin", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
if (file.is_open())
{
    size = file.tellg();
    memblock = new char [size];
    file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    file.read (memblock, size);
    file.close();

    cout << "the entire file content is in memory";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += sizeof(int))
    {
        cout << *(int*)&memblock[i] << endl;
    }


    delete[] memblock;
}
else 
    cout << "Unable to open file";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the format of your "binary" file? If you don't know that, you can't write this program. I suspect you may have misunderstood your homework exercise.

Comment: Do you understand what the cast `(int*)` is doing?

Comment: Isn't size==0 this way? or even -1

Comment: What is the value of `size`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the endless loop with a small file. How large is your file?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: i suspect that the execution will end eventually, its just boring watching a stream of ints go by

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory.  You can read one `uint8_t` at a time or `int` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to implement your requirements:

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int quantity = 0U;
  ifstream file ("threesData.bin", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
  uint8_t byte;
  while (file >> byte)
  {
    if (byte == 3U)
    {
      ++ quantity;
    }
  }
  cout << "The quantity of 3s is: " << quantity << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The first step should always get a simple version working first.  Only optimize if necessary.

Allocating memory for a file and reading the entire file is an optimization.  For example, your platform may not have enough available memory to read the *entire* file into memory before processing.